# Pandas NameError: name 'merge' is not defined

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

Trying to merge two data frames:

`ds.head()` gives me:

```
Out[35]:
yearID  teamID  lgID    playerID    salary
0   1985    BAL AL  murraed02   1472819
1   1985    BAL AL  lynnfr01    1090000
2   1985    BAL AL  ripkeca01   800000
3   1985    BAL AL  lacyle01    725000
4   1985    BAL AL  flanami01   641667
```

dt[:3] gives me:
[image: Screenshot]

I need to merge two tables by yearID and teamID. I do:

```
merge(ds, dt, on='yearID')
```

Why do I get? I couldn't find explanation online for this error for 'merge'. And I have no idea what it wants from me. Ideally I need to merge two tables and sort them by teamID by yearID.

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-2087923fc223> in <module>()
----> 1 merge(ds, dt, on='yearID')

NameError: name 'merge' is not defined
```

**ADDED 03/08**
My goal is to merge these two tables to create a new one, that will show wins and salary for each team for each year.
What I did is:

```
merged = pd.merge(ds, dt, on=['teamID', 'yearID'])
grouped = merged.groupby(['teamID', 'yearID'])
aggregated = grouped.aggregate(np.sum)
aggregated.head()
```

Is that the best way to do it? It looks to me that it is not the best approach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you're receiving is because you're not calling the pandas module along with the [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge) method.

An example of merging would be:

```
import pandas as pd 

merged_df = pd.merge(ds, dt, how='inner',on=['yearID','teamID'])
```

I declared the how parameter so you can see that you can change this as needed.